# How to auto refresh page when call is not initiated

Tags: refresh, webrtc

I'm thinking about script to refresh page in chrome automatically every 5 or 10 seconds. But with one exception. It should not refresh when `WebRTC` session is active via browser to avoid disconnecting calls. Any ideas?

EDIT: or it could be: if in page www.aaa.com user clicked button recently - do not refresh page for 15 minutes, otherwise refresh every 5 or 10 second. Something like this.

EDIT: i can refresh page with chrome add-ins. Then the question is how to stop refreshing. It can be stopped when calls answer button pops up, but how to catch it in chrome, so i can stop refreshing?

Here is simple `javascript` code to refresh every ten minutes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",600000);
  function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1200000);
  }
</script>
```

I'm thinking about workaround.
How can i do that if i click specific button on page to refresh after 20 minutes (function resetTimeout) (let's say calls wont be longer) and after 20 minutes to refresh again every 10 minutes? 
How to incorporate this script to browser for particular webpage?

Comment: Why would you refresh the page anyways? It seems like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I know... just the providers of the service are not doing their job so i will make temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i installed chrome injector and for particular page I need to write simple script like this:

```
   var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);
  function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(10000000);
  }
   function resetTimeout2() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(10000);
  }

$('.button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.pull-left.call').click(resetTimeout());
$('.button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger.pull-left.disabled.hangup').click(resetTimeout2());
```

Refresh page every 6000000ms. If pressed answer then refresh every 10000000ms. If pressed hangup refresh again every 6000000ms. I just need help with syntax with javascript.
when i pressed left.call button resetTimout() do not work, it still refreshes page immediately.

button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.pull-left.call and the other one is Button Class element

Comment: it is actually working when i'm not referring to function, but write instead:
.click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000000);
});